# Boxentriq level 20 with dancing figures and a book cipher

Tags: knowledge, cipher

The picture below is a puzzle from the [Boxentriq](https://www.boxentriq.com/) game, which should help me find a particular book.

Decoding the pictured [Dancing Men cipher](https://www.boxentriq.com/code-breaking/dancing-men-cipher) gives me "LIBERAL II". Using this and the numbers at the bottom of the image I have to find a hidden message via a book cipher.
However, I cannot pinpoint the book in question - **can anyone help identify it from this information?**

[image: puzzle]

Answer (score 2):

The trick is

> There is an omitted space in the book title. What you are actually clued/ searching for is LIBER AL

This leads to

> Liber AL vel Legis, the book of laws.

A copy can be found

> here: https://lib.oto-usa.org/libri/liber0220.html

Note

> There is an additional step after identifying the correct parts of the text. It's clued in the second hint in the app.